# Node/Express.js csrf with passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, csrf, passport.js

I am using node with express.js and passport.js as my authentication framework.

I setup csrf protection built in express.js using below code.

```
app.use(express.csrf());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.token = req.csrfToken();
  next();
});
```

My route:

```
app.post('/passportlogin', passport.authenticate('local-login', {....}), function(req, res){...});
```

I have a hidden field in my login form with name='_csrf' and I confirm a token was initialized. When I submit the form (POST) to passport authentication, express returns a 403 unforbidden error as below.

Any idea how to setup csrf with express & passport?

```
Express
403 Error: Forbidden
at Object.exports.error (node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\utils.js:63:13)
at createToken (node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\csrf.js:82:55)
at Object.handle (node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\csrf.js:48:24)
at next (node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
at Object.handle (node_modules\connect-flash\lib\flash.js:21:5)
at next (node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass (node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:314:9)
at SessionStrategy.authenticate (node_modules\passport\lib\strategies\session.js:67:10)
at attempt (node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:337:16)
at Object.authenticate [as handle] (node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:338:7)
```

Comment: Obvious I know, but is the `_csrf` field in your form actually inheriting the `token` value you set? i.e. are you seeing something like this in your form: `<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="SOME TOKEN VALUE" />`

Comment: Hmm re-reading, the error seems to imply an issue with picking up the token from the request. Is connect parsing your form correctly? http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body

Comment: Yes, I tried a POST on a non passport route and csrf works like a charm. But does not work with passport.

Comment: Interesting. What order do you have your `use` statements in? (i.e. for body parsing, csrf and passport respectively) -- some other posts here suggest that may come into play.